# Prevent Duplicate Documents in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to figure out the best way to prevent duplicate documents from being saved in MongoDB.

Right now my form takes the user_url from the user. The logic is:

- Check if the user_url is valid. (dns.lookup)
- If user_url is new, save it to the database and return url_ID.
- If user_url is old, just return the url_ID.

I think my 2 options are:

```
var findOneURL = function(user_url, done) {
    URL.findOne({
        orig_url: user_url
    }, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            done(err);
        }
        done(null, data);
    })
}
```

or

```
var findEditThenSave = function(user_url, done) {
    URL.findById(user_url, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            done(err);
        }

        data.save((err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                done(err);
            }
            done(null, data);
        });
    })
};
```

It's not working terribly well at the moment but this is the live version:
https://kindly-fisherman.glitch.me/

EDIT2: I think I got it working properly now. Here's my logic:

**Saving to database:** dns.lookup -> findByURL -> *(If it doesn't exist)* -> countURLs -> findAndUpdateURL -> Return what was saved to database.

**OR** -> *(If it exists)* -> Return the record.

**Retrieving from database:** findByID

Comment: Since you are using `mongoose` you can use `unique: true` property in the model.  https://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/schematypes.html

Comment: I would suggest to use unique index on single field.  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/. This will throw an error while inserting duplicate row. Based on the error code you can easily find out this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best choice is `findOneAndUpdate` query with `upsert` and `returnNewDocument` options

```
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate({ orig_url: user_url }, { $set: { orig_url: user_url }}, { upsert: true, returnNewDocument: true })
```

In mongoose

```
URL.findOneAndUpdate({orig_url: user_url }, { $set: { orig_url: user_url }}, { upsert: true, new: true }, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        done(err);
    }
    // data will contain your document
    done(null, data);
});
```

`upsert` option specifies whether to insert document if not found, `new` (returnNewDocument in mongo's console) - whether to return old or updated document - if false (default is false) you will have null for inserted documents.

Comment: I replaced the .save with .findOneAndUpdate. It works if the record already exists (ie: www.google.ca), but when I try to add a new record it's throwing an error.
EDIT: Oh, it's updating the original record to the new count! And then when I try to add a new item it's confused because it wants to use the new count as well. ... I'll go try & sort it out.

Comment: @AdamWeiler sorry Adam, I dont know much about `count`'s logic, if you give me more details I will be able to help you

Comment: tl;dr: It's working okay now. 

Basically I created a flaw in the database. I had 6 records, and while I was working I used findOneAndUpdate, and accidentally gave a record "id=7". 6 records, but "id=7". Count returns how many records exist. For adding a new record I run Count and add 1, so it'll always be a new number. But, since I'd already used "id=7", the new record was being rejected since it also wanted "id=7". As soon as I fixed the database, everything was golden.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
 db.insert()
```

you should use

```
db.update()
```

and specify

```
$upsert: true
```

[here]